# Toggle element when value is selected without know any information about value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've a problem here and don't know the right path to get this working. I have a table where I store some values and of course I can do CRUD operations on any records. Those values are used to build a `SELECT` element dynamically. All this works perfectly but I need to toggle one element visibility when specific value is picked. For example:

```
<select class="change">
  <option value="1">Value 1</option>
  <option value="2">Value 2</option>
  <option value="3">Value 3</option>
</select>

<input type="text" class="show" style="display:none" />
```

Taking this as input, by default `.show` is hide, lets said that any time I choose "Value 2" it will be displayed otherwise should be hidden again. I know how to do this at jQuery with this code:

```
$(".change").on('change', function() {
    option = $('.change :selected').val();
    if (option == "Value 2") {
        $(".show").show();
    } else {
        $(".show").hide();
    }
});
```

But what's happen if any edit "Value 2" and change it to "VAlue 2" or "VALue 2" or "Value2"? The code will stop working. In this case what did yours do to avoid this?

I can attach to "ID" but again what's happen if any deletes the record with ID=2 and recreate later with ID=10? Then code will stop working again.

I don't know how to get this done, any advice? Ideas? Workarounds?

Comment: you need to know something... either somebody need to pass the value against which you want to compare as a configuration or it should be a constant...

Comment: The code you wrote doesn't even work. The value is `2`, not `Value 2`.

Comment: Should it always be the second option, no matter what its value or text is? Then use `$('.change :selected').index()` to get its position.

Comment: Or maybe you can attach a class to the element, and test that.

Comment: @Barmar just a typo should be `option = $('.change :selected').text();` instead of `option = $('.change :selected').val();` and no, not always is the second option, that's the problem, I don't have any info just the text but as I said any can change the text and code stop working

Comment: There needs to be SOME way to know which one of the options should cause you to show the other input. The computer can't read minds.

Comment: Yes, all of yours are right the only path I see here is to build SELECT static and not allow to change it

Comment: @ReynierPM, just an idea from Barmar. You have to rely on the value of the attribute `value` in `select` tag. So that whatever changes you might done in the text, the value will be **still**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are building your dropdown list using data from DB. What I suggest is to add a new column in your table. This column will be a simple bool to determine if your input needs to be hidden or no.

Then you have this HTML code (here new col is "showInput"):

```
<select class="js-dropdown">
    <option value="foo" data-showInput="1">Foo</option>
    <option value="bar" data-showInput="0">Bar</option>
    <option value="foobar" data-showInput="1">Foobar</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="js-input" />
```

And this JS code:

```
var input = $(body).find('.js-input');

$('.js-dropdown').on('change', function() {
    var option = $(this).find(':selected');
    var showInput = parseInt(option.attr('data-showInput'));

    if (showInput === 1) {
        input.show();
    } else {
        input.hide();
    }
});
```